# In Apache, can I make a second request internally

Tags: apache, http

In my Apache web server, I would like to be able to retrieve a page for a given GET request, and then also make a second internal request, to add additional response headers, based on certain request criteria.

For instance, if the URL in the GET request includes certain query parameters, like this:

```
/my/page.html?add-debug-headers=true
```

then I would like to be able to retrieve `my/page.html` and then (ideally from Apache) run a separate PHP script (or similar) to add some debug response headers. Since the specific response headers might differ depending on the a number of factors, I don't want to add the PHP code directly into the `my/page.html` code - ideally I don't want to have to change any of my existing pages to add this functionality - hence the fact that I'm trying to do it from within Apache.

Does this make sense? If so, is it do-able?

Comment: I don't think making another request would make sense, but you can add headers to responswe conditionally. Can you make your question more specific? For example: "If request contains `add-debug-headers=true` parameter, then add which header to response?

Comment: @DusanBajic well here's where it gets complicated - I need to return a number of headers, based on various request headers - information about the requestor (user agent, IP etc.) and also possibly mirror back some of the request headers.

Comment: Apache configuration is probably less flexible (in what you can achieve) than "proper" programming language, but it still might be doable.

Comment: Oh well I can write the code in any number of languages - it's just I want to be able to *call* that code from the Apache config, after the main request, to add the headers. That's where I'm having a problem.